# Retrieving all XML from nodes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to get the xml from nodes. Let's say I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<story title="My title here">
    <subject key="key1" caption="Intro">
        Text here for subject 1. There might be an occasional <html> markup present.
        <action tag="actiontag"/>
    </subject>
    <subject key="key2" caption="Chap1">
        Text for chapter 2
        <directions>
            <dir go="chap5" to="Solving"/>
            <dir go="chap12" to="Searching">
                <extra1 subtitle="subtitle">You can expect extra text here as well.</extra>
                <extra2 subtitle="subtitle2"/>
            </dir>
            <dir go="chap2,chap5" to="Finding"/>
        </directions>
    </subject>
    <chapters key="chap1" caption="Chapter1">
        The text for chapter1 goes here
        <newtag>This one has text as well</newtag>
    </chapters>
</story>
```

Now I'm trying to get the whole XML code including nodes and tags into an array of objects. So the result should ideally be:

```
subjects[0].key=key1
subjects[0].caption=Intro
subjects[0].txt=Text here for subject 1. There might be an occasional <html> markup present.<action tag="actiontag"/>
subjects[1].key=key2
subjects[1].caption=Chap1
subjects[1].txt=Text for chapter 2<directions><dir go="chap5" to="Solving"/><dir go="chap12" to="Searching"><extra1 subtitle="subtitle">You can expect extra text here as well.</extra><extra2 subtitle="subtitle2"/></dir><dir go="chap2,chap5" to="Finding"/></directions>
```

This 'text' can than later be processed as XML.
Now I've been able to read the XML and access the tags separately. I've been able to traverse through the file and get the text but I can't seem to loop through all the nodes/text/tags and keep it formatted as is.

What I have is:

```
var xmlDoc;

function loadxml() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "assets/myfile.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    xmlhttp.onloadend = init(xmlDoc);
}

function init(xmlDoc) {
    var subjects = [];
    var x, i;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('subject');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        subjects.push({ key: x[i].getAttribute('key'), caption: x[i].getAttribute('caption'), txt: x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue });
    }
    //just to check if there's something recorded..
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = subjects[1].txt;
}
```

The array of objects is no problem, that works. But how do I change x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue to hold all the childnodes of [subject] and keep accompanying tags and formatting?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but do you really need code for IE6 and below?

Comment: that may be much more easier using jQuery, try $.parseXML()

Comment: He already has a parsed XML document, @derloopkat, from `xmlhttp.responseXML`.

Comment: How are you going to use the value of `subject`? Because if you're just going to do further parsing on it, use `txt: x[i].childNodes[0]` so that you have a Node to work off of. If you're appending it to the DOM, use `appendChild(subjects[1].txt)` rather than `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: IE6 and below is not necessary. It was a quick copy & paste from the web.

Not sure how to process the childNodes. Eventually I need the tags from that and process depending on the contents of the tag.  What I'm struggling with at the moment is to get a clear view on how to process the childNodes. My first thought would be to process the .txt as XML document from string.

Comment: Do you want your result to be an array of subjects, each subject having:

- key property that comes from the subject's key attribute in the xml
- action property that comes from the subject's action attribute in the xml
- txt property that comes from the subject's text node and all of its children

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadxml() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "assets/myfile.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
    textNodes = responseText.split(/<subject.*>/);
    textNodes.shift();   //remove first chunk of text
    for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++) {
        textNodes[i] = textNodes[i].replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '');   //remove line breaks;
        textNodes[i] = textNodes[i].replace(/^\s*/, '');      // Replace "> " with ">"
        textNodes[i] = textNodes[i].replace(/>\s*/g, '>');      // Replace "> " with ">"
        textNodes[i] = textNodes[i].replace(/\s*</g, '<');      // Replace "< " with "<"
    }
    xmlhttp.onloadend = init(xmlDoc, textNodes);
}

function init(xmlDoc, textNodes) {
    var subjects = [];
    var x, i;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('subject');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        subjects.push({ key: x[i].getAttribute('key'), caption: x[i].getAttribute('caption'), txt: textNodes[i] });
    }
    console.log(subjects);
}
```

Comment: This answer accomplishes your goal by using the ajax response's responseXML _and_ responseText.  The responseXML is useful for getting each subject and its corresponding `key` and `caption` attribute.  The responseText is useful for getting each subject's txt in the format you're looking for: with the newlines and whitespace stripped but preserving all of the markup within the text node.

Comment: You are absolutely right, `xmlhttp.responseText` is the magic word here. Minor detail is that the end-tag is still in place but that's easily fixed. Thanks!